# Bootstrap tabs not working inside modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

i am using tabs in bootstrap modal bootstrap tab get data from database 
when i use onclick="javascript:$('#myModal').modal('show');" here () i get id from database and show content against that id  but i am facing issue that first model with tabs working fine but when open second model their tabs not switching.
sample code is bellow...

```
<button class="btn btn-default" onclick="javascript:$('#myModal<?php echo $cid;?>').modal('show');">Click     Me</button>

<div id="myModal<?php echo $cid;?>" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
                    <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#home" aria-controls="home"     role="tab"
                                                              data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
                    <li role="presentation"><a href="#profile" aria-controls="profile" role="tab"
                                               data-toggle="tab">Profile</a></li>
                    <li role="presentation"><a href="#messages" aria-controls="messages" role="tab"
                                               data-toggle="tab">Messages</a></li>
                    <li role="presentation"><a href="#settings" aria-controls="settings" role="tab"
                                               data-toggle="tab">Settings</a></li>
                </ul>
                <div class="tab-content">
                    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="home">Home</div>
                    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="profile">Profile</div>
                    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="messages">Messages</div>
                    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="settings">Settings</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Does your modal, or any of its parent elements have a `tabindex` attribute?

Comment: no i am not using tabindex attribute

Comment: I had tested your code, and I haven't seen any problem try this https://jsfiddle.net/3svdffyo/

Comment: @ConstantinUncuță issue is that its working fine when not connected with database but look at my code i am getting #myModal(<?php echo $cid;?>) and id from database that changes so when i get id from database and its change this make issue....

Answer (score 0):

Remove `tabindex="-1"` from modal. Then it will work.

Answer (score 0):

In bootstrap 4.5, the css classes "nav nav-tabs" need to add for ul like this:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
<li>.........
</ul>
```